# How to keep login information for web performance test

Tags: web-applications, cookies, authentication

I am using VS2012 webtest to run load test against a CRM online application. But all the cases failed becuase login failure.

If I managed to write the login code for each case, it will slow down the test speed and the load will not be high enough.

So is there any way login only ONCE at the beginning of the case execution and save the cookie for later use?  (Well, I am considering injecting the cookie into my request headers though I am not sure if save the cookie only is enough for authentication.)

Comment: This is a function of the web application being tested, not a function of the web test framework.

Comment: Also, IMHO, if logging in slows the test too much, then I would suggest that you should spend some time optimizing the login process.

Comment: The VS2012 webtest sends HTTP requests directly to server. No browser is involved. So even there's cookie in my disk. I cannot rely on the browser to pick it up. So I need to include the cookie in my HTTP requests, and this needs to be done by my test framework.

Comment: And what makes you think that the web test framework doesn't handle this very common piece of functionality? If you test the steps: login, perform operation, perform other operation, etc., then the cookie from the first step will still be present in the subsequent steps, and login will not be required.